# Restriction of surjective linear map is isomorphism

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $U,V$ be finite-dimensional $K$-vector spaces, and let $T:U\to V$ be a surjective linear map. Show there is a subspace $W\subset U$ such that $T_{|W}:W\to V$ is an isomorphism of $K$-vector spaces.

My immediate thought is that we have the quotient
$$
U/\ker T\cong V,
$$
but I am not sure how to show this quotient is a subspace of $U$. Can we always embed a quotient into the original space, or should we be doing something completely different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**:

Consider the restriction of $T$ to any complement of $\ker T$.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct.  $K=\ker T$ is always a subspace of $U$, and so the quotient space
$$ U / \ker T = \{u + K : u \in U \} $$
is well defined and satisfies the first isomorphism theorem as you point out.  So all that's left to prove is that this quotient space is isomorphic to a subspace of $U$.  Well let's try the natural choice, the quotient map $Q : U / \ker T \to U$ as
$$ Q(u+K) = u $$
Note that $Q$ is linear since 
$$Q(\alpha (u_1+K) + (u_2 +K))= Q((\alpha u_1 + u_2 )+K) = \alpha u_1 + u_2 = \alpha Q(u_1 + K) + Q(u_2+K)$$
Note that $Q$ is injective, since the kernel of $Q$ contains only one element, $\{0+K\}$.  Finally note that the image of $Q$ is contained in $U$.

Comment: How do you define $Q(v+K)$ when $v+K=u+K$?

Comment: Really I mean to define $Q$ on equivalency classes $[u]=\{ x \in U : x-u \in K \} = \{ x \in U : x+K =  u+K \} $ for which $u$ is the representative. Pretty sure it needs Axiom of Choice to guarantee we have a representative

Comment: Yes, it would require a choice function.